# How to pass data from one class to WPf main app to display on screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class running some data and as it runs I want to pass some of that data back to the main WPF page to display oin the screen (inside a textblock/richtextblock,etc).
How do I pass this data from my class back to the MainWindow.xaml.cs class to bind to the textblock in the MainWindow.xaml page?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a combination of WPF Data Binding, and classes which implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Take some time to familiarize yourself with the "MVVM" development model, which addresses your question. This approach to architecture addresses almost all the data-formatting needs in a WPF program.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/10/01/mvvm-in-5-minutes.aspx

Comment: can't I use delegates?

Comment: You can use delegates to make the different classes exchange information, but like mentioned above, you need to implement binding in order for the data to reflect in the UI.